# Count from a certain cell until a blank cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I'm trying to create a dynamic formula which counts all the rows from cell D3 downwards until a blank cell is reached. I want to be able to add new data everyday and have the range automatically update and include the most recent data to give a series of subtotals and averages.

What is the formula to have a range that includes cells from D3 until the next blank cell that will update and include new data when the last blank cell is filled in with data from a new day?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do and where you need the `range`? Are you trying to define a named range that is dynamic that you can use in other formulas?

Comment: In column C I have 2 rows of headers, then the data starts in D3 this is added to day by day as it displays the total downloads for each day. The data currently reaches D297 before there is a total box in D303. I want to have a range so the total is updated every time a cell between D298 and D302 is filled in (ie not blank). As more data is added, the total box will move down as I insert new lines to contain more data so I want to range to expand to the top of the totals box (ie one cell above the total box).

Comment: Your total box is a sum or a count of non-blank contiguous cells?

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you need to count cells (your first sentence) or do you need to do something with the data that's not blank?

Comment: I want to have a named range that contains all the cells containing data in my column D going from D3 until theres a blank cell. This should then create a dynamic formula which should include new data when it's added on a daily basis

Comment: Please clarify your question to include your requirements as well as what you've tried already

Answer (score 3):

Let me make sure I have this straight:

- You have a lot of data in Column D that you want totaled.
- Rows 1 & 2 are header rows, and contain text.
- Rows 3 and below, in column D, contain values to be totaled.
- Below the data to be totaled, there is a cell in which you want the total to be placed.
- There may or may not be blank cells between the data to be totaled, and the cell which displays the data.

Given the above, if you do not actually *need* a named range for other purposes, the formula is fairly simple:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("D3:D",CELL("row")-1)))
```

Walkthrough:

- **SUM** adds up all the numeric values (automatically excluding blanks and non-numeric values) within the specified cells.
- **INDIRECT** allows you to build a cell reference via formula.
- **CONCATENATE** lets you join portions of strings, and formula results, into one string.
- **"D3:D"** is the first part of the reference we'll eventually want passed to SUM.

  - This identifies a cell range that starts at D3, and will end at another cell in column D.
  - Since it's being provided as a string instead of an actual cell reference, this won't get changed if the cell is moved or copied - the range will always point to column D, and always start at row 3.
- **CELL** lets you get information about a cell. Here, we're getting the row number for the current cell. This is what allows the formula to automatically adjust the row number no matter where it is placed.
- **-1** is used to subtract 1 from the row number returned by CELL, thus referencing the row above the current cell.

For D303, this will effectively be the same as:

```
=SUM(D3:D302)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer here: [In Excel 2010, how can I create a template with a function automatically ends in the last cell with data?](https://superuser.com/questions/620881/in-excel-2010-how-can-i-create-a-template-with-a-function-automatically-ends-in/620923#620923) may be of use.

I strongly recommend tables if you're able, they also have a built in total row function.

If not fall back on the dynamic named range.

**EDIT**
As we've discussed, you want to be able to use a dynamic named range as the source range for a pivot table:

This requires some slight modification to the dynamic named range. Firstly you'll need your range to include your column titles, so the pivot table has headings, and then you will need to expand your range across all relevant columns.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F$1:$F$12),COUNTA(Sheet1!$F$1:$G$1))
```

Here you can see that instead of ending the formula with `),)` we've added a column reference that returns the range of columns by covering the 1st row across all needed columns.

When you insert a pivot table use the name of this range.

***NOTES***
Wrapping the OFFSET in a COUNT of any kind won't work if you want to use the named range in a pivot table, but it isn't necessary, as you can just run the count on the pivot table.

If you and your users are all using 2007 or up then use a table instead, this will remain dynamic even if you add more columns, and will never require you to go in a and increase the height of the named range. You will still be able to refer the table to a pivot table.

Comment: ok I think all I need is to modify the end of this formula:=OFFSET(SheetName!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(SheetName!$A$2:$A$500),) so that the Counta counts down from A2 until the next blank cell. This will give me the dynamic range I'm after. So I just need the formula of 'count until blank cell' to replace A500

Comment: That formula is the closest thing I know of to a true `next blank row` calculation. The only thing that isn't dynamic is that you have set a max range. I don't believe there is a way to make it truly dynamic, unless you use VBA or something too esoteric for my knowledge. How big do you expect your data range to get? Simply set the 500 to be higher than the max you think it will ever get to.
If you truly cannot work with a stated range like this then again I reccomend Excel tabels, as these will be truly dynamic.

Comment: So you'd end up with a formula that would look like this: =COUNTA(MyRange)  Where the MyRange name would create a range from A2 (or whatever you select) to the first blank in that column, where it will not go higher than the max range stated at the end of the named range formula

Comment: Ok I now have a formula Counta(D3:D305) which selects all the cells I want in my range. How do I convert this formula into a range?

Comment: Create a named range like this `=OFFSET(SheetName!$D$3,0,0,COUNTA(SheetName!$D$3:$D$400),)` (note the D400; there's no harm in adding a little wiggle room) then your formula is `=COUNTA(RangeName)` The formula for the sum wouldn't be a range, however if you want to be able to call on the result of the formula anywhere, then save it as a named formula, or make this the whole named range: `=COUNTA(OFFSET(SheetName!$D$3,0,0,COUNTA(SheetName!$D$3:$D$400),))`, you could then place the result anywhere by simply entering `=MyNamedFormula` or whatever name you gave it, in a cell

Comment: Thanks, that works for getting the exact number of lines that aren't blank within a range but what I really need is for it to display the range so I can make a pivot table from it. i.e. where the dotted lines appear around the range so I can make a dynamic pivot table selection from it where the pivot table automatically adds data day by day depending on what new info is included in the original doc

Comment: Now that would have been useful to know in the first place :D     See my update to the answer

Comment: Hi @Charlie, would be very useful to know whether this solved your query